# Will copy constructor be called when calling insert of std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor, unordered-map

I have a std::unordered_map and I found that the object I insert into it is different from that I got from it by using for range traversing.

I doubt that there might be some object copying happening here but after I added some dumping to the copy constructor, it is not called at all.

Could any one tell me what is happening in the background when inserting and traversing a std::unordered_map.

I tried the following code and it dumped:

[Result]

```
mypair constuctor
mypair constuctor
string1 address:0x7ffccb813ba0
string2 address:0x7ffccb813bd0
++++++++++++++++
auto &x address:0x55fb40529378
string2: 0.5
auto &x address:0x55fb405292c8
string1: 0.3
++++++++++++++++
auto x address:0x7ffccb813c00
string2: 0.5
auto x address:0x7ffccb813c00
string1: 0.3
++++++++++++++++
```

[Source]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class mypair : public std::pair<std::string,double> {
public:
      mypair(std::string str, double num):std::pair<std::string,double>(str, num) {
          std::cout<<"mypair constuctor"<<std::endl;
      }
      mypair( const mypair& ) {
          std::cout<<"mypair copy constuctor"<<std::endl;
      }
      mypair& operator=(const mypair&) {
          std::cout<<"mypair copy assignment"<<std::endl;
          return *this;
      }
};

int main ()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string,double> myMap;
    mypair string1 ("string1", 0.3);
    mypair string2 ("string2", 0.5);
    std::cout << "string1 address:" << &string1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "string2 address:" << &string2 << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"++++++++++++++++"<< std::endl;
    myMap.insert (string1);
    myMap.insert (string2);
    
    for (auto& x: myMap) {
        std::cout << "auto &x address:"<< &x << std::endl<< x.first << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout <<"++++++++++++++++"<< std::endl;
    
    for (auto x: myMap) {
        std::cout << "auto x address:"<< &x << std::endl<< x.first << ": " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout <<"++++++++++++++++"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags unless you want to use both of them together or you ask about differences. There is nothing that seems to be related to C language.

Comment: you aren't inserting `mypair` into the map, you're copying its values instead which is why you don't see any prints

Comment: This is a case of  Object Slicing. `std::unordered_map` uses `std::pair` by value. If you try to use a type that derives from `std::pair` instead, the map will only copy the `std::pair` part of it and "slice the rest of the object off".

Answer (score 5):

You're not seeing any calls to the copy constructor of `mypair`, because that is not the pair type that the `std::unordered_map` uses internally.

```cpp
using value_type = std::pair<const Key, Value>;
```

... is the pair type that is actually used inside. Your `mypair` is implicitly convertible to the `value_type`, so the following member function should be called:

```cpp
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( P&& value );
```

This neither copies nor copy-assigns a `mypair`, it will construct a `std::pair` from the contents of the pair you pass.

If you want to minimize copying and overhead as much as possible, you should instead use `emplace` or `try_emplace`.